# I want to signin from first wordpress site to other wordpress website without registration..without using network mode

Tags: single, wp-login-form, signup, single-sign-on

i have a wordpress website installed (without multisite wordpress network feature) on server so i want to login to other wordpress website with same credentials.. in-details: i want to create a link so, when user sign in into first website then he/she clicks on a single link and then automatically he signup(is not signup before means new user )/ signin (if exiting user) into second website ...

Link code :

Comment: Link code : 'code' <li class="menu-item" ><a href="<?php echo Noo_Member::get_endpoint_url('shop')?>" style="white-space: nowrap;"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i> <?php _e('Assessments','noo')?></a></li>'code'

Comment: can any budy have the answer......

Comment: any luck........